# Why my form in Django is not valid ? Never do the condition

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to save the default data of my form and model with a simple function in Django but when I use the condition of is_valid() never enter to the condition. What can I do ?

This is for views.py

```
def entreno1B(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=Entreno(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("is valid")
            form.save()
return render(request, 'training/entrenosB1.html')
```

my model is

```
class Entrenos(models.Model):
    tiempo1D1 = models.FloatField(max_length=1000,default=0.0)
    tiempo2D1 = models.FloatField(max_lenght=1000,default=0.0)
```

and my form is

```
class Entreno(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Entrenos
       fields = ('tiempo1D1','tiempo2D1',)
```

Please Help. I don't know what is my error. Thank you

Also, when I modify my views like this:

```
def entreno1B(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=Entreno(request.POST)
        form.save()
        if form.is_valid():
            print("is valid")
            form.save()
return render(request, 'training/entrenosB1.html')
```

I got the error that my object has no attibute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: can you provide the html of the form page?

Comment: I'm not using my form in a HTML template, I'm trying to save a data that I generated in function that I created. In my HTML I have a Button with a method POST, I want to run my function always that the user push the button.

Answer (score 1):

I modify my function in views.py, and works. I do this:

```
def entreno1B(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form=Entreno({'tiempo1D1':DATA, 'tiempo2D1':Data2})
    if form.is_valid():
        print("is valid")
        form.save()
```

return render(request, 'training/entrenosB1.html')

Comment: I added the forms field values, and it solved it. `form=myForm({'field1':data1, 'field2':data2})`.